# how to create inheritance table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there is table called event that act as parent the child inherit tables of event are special event and hotel event i have created the types as bellow but I'm contuse about how to create tables to these tables in oracle.I have referred most of the currently available solutions within Stack overflow, git hub etc. However, none of these solutions have worked out successfully.

Table types :

```
Event_t (
  EventID:char(5),
  EventType:varchar(20),
  VenueName:varchar(50),
  NoOfGuest:number(10)
) NOT FINAL

HotelEvent_t (
  Date:date,
  Price:numbr(8,2)
) UNDER Event_t

SpecialEvent_t (
  BookingDate:date,
  EndDate:date,
  MenuNumber:number(2), 
  Reservation ref Reservation_t
) UNDER event_t
```

Thank you very much and any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your types using the correct syntax:

```sql
CREATE TYPE Event_t AS OBJECT(
  EventID   char(5),
  EventType varchar(20),
  VenueName varchar(50),
  NoOfGuest number(10)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE HotelEvent_t UNDER Event_t (
  datetime date,                -- Date is a keyword, try to use a different name.
  Price  number(8,2)
);

CREATE TYPE SpecialEvent_t UNDER event_t (
  BookingDate date,
  EndDate     date,
  MenuNumbers NUMBER(2),
  Reservation ref Reservation_t
);
```

Then you can create an object table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Events OF Event_T(
  eventid CONSTRAINT Events__EventID__PK PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then you can insert the different types into it:

```sql
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(
  HotelEvent_T(
    'H1',
    'HOTEL',
    'Venue1',
    42,
    DATE '0001-02-03' + INTERVAL '04:05:06' HOUR TO SECOND,
    123456.78
  )
);

INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(
  SpecialEvent_T(
    'SE1',
    'SPECIAL',
    'Time Travel Convention',
    -1,
    SYSDATE,
    TRUNC(SYSDATE),
    0,
    NULL
  )
);
```

and get the data out of it:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
       TREAT( VALUE(e) AS HotelEvent_T ).datetime AS datetime,
       TREAT( VALUE(e) AS HotelEvent_T ).price AS price,
       TREAT( VALUE(e) AS SpecialEvent_T ).bookingdate AS bookingdate,
       TREAT( VALUE(e) AS SpecialEvent_T ).enddate AS enddate,
       TREAT( VALUE(e) AS SpecialEvent_T ).menunumbers AS menunumbers
FROM   Events e;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> EVENTID | EVENTTYPE | VENUENAME              | NOOFGUEST | DATETIME            |     PRICE | BOOKINGDATE         | ENDDATE             | MENUNUMBERS
> :------ | :-------- | :--------------------- | --------: | :------------------ | --------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | ----------:
> H1      | HOTEL     | Venue1                 |        42 | 0001-02-03 04:05:06 | 123456.78 | null                | null                |        null
> SE1     | SPECIAL   | Time Travel Convention |        -1 | null                |      null | 2020-03-30 21:11:22 | 2020-03-30 00:00:00 |           0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e620ec910a1be575612330087b42d70)*

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to create these tables in Oracle would be:

```
create table event_t (
  event_id char(5) primary key not null,
  event_type varchar2(20),
  venue_mame varchar2(50),
  no_of_guest number(10)
);

create table hotel_event_t (
  event_date date,
  price number(8,2),
  event_id char(5),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (event_id) references event_t (event_id)
);

create table special_event_t (
  booking_date date,
  end_date date,
  menu_number number(2), 
  reservation_id char(5),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (reservation_id) 
    references reservation_t (reservation_id),
  event_id char(5),
  constraint fk3 foreign key (event_id) references event_t (event_id)
);
```

Comment: You forgot setting the emp_id as primary key of the first table as fk to a tables key refers that primary kwy its referencing